# How to move cube in unity3d & C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all I apologize that this texts looks so weird.
It's my first time to use stackoverflow

I start to learn about Unity and C#.

And today I learn about move cube in unity, gonna review the script and I think i failed.

I put script in cube1 at Hierarchy, click the solution build at C# and run at unity.
And didn't work.

```cs
public class TRAIN : MonoBehaviour
{
    // return cube1 to cube. cube1 is name of cube object in unity
    GameObject cube = GameObject.Find("cube1");   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //move cube1 to z-axis at speed 1
        cube.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, 1);  
    }
}
```

How can I move cube1?

Comment: Also you need to multiply the vector3 added to cube.transform.position with Time.DeltaTime to make the cube move at a smooth speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call `GameObject.Find()` directly there, you should be getting an error in the console.

> UnityException: Find is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead

Do it in the `Awake()` or `Start()` instead.

```
public class TRAIN : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject cube; 

    void Start()
    {
        cube = GameObject.Find("cube1");
    }
```

Comment: I really thanks for your comment! That's the what i have to do! It works very well, I will pay it forward.